# TextFieldParser equivalent in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, csv, frameworks

Is there a modern .NET equivalent to the `TextFieldParser` class in VB6? Performance is a lot lower than a simple `String.Split()`

Comment: What do you mean the performance is a lot lower?  Have you benchmarked?

Comment: I dont get it ..`TextFieldParser` is part of the .NET library

Comment: @David L yeas first I've readed a benchmark here http://www.dotnetperls.com/textfieldparser and after that I benchmarkered by myself to see the results, is too many times lower.

Comment: @meda is part of the old VisualBasic so it's a wrapper for .NET if I'm not wrong, like Left, Right, and those old VB methods

Comment: no, it is in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` - not the compatibility layer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx  I have seen that benchmark before and dont doubt it - I am sure the class is some sort of wrapper like `Mid` and `Left` and so forth are.

Comment: Do you want to read some csv file? Or you want to use simw modern class for it?

Comment: some >100K guy made a comment recently that parsing CSVs using String.Split was evil/stupid/bad, but never expanded on any alternatives.  I doubt `TextFieldParser` was the answer because everyone knows it is slow and since it is in a VB space, it is one of those high-level things for the less experienced (arguably).

Comment: @Vyacheslav Yudanov I know how to use both Split method and TextFieldparser, Just I want to know if exist a modern/faster .NET alternative Class than the slower TextFieldParser, but anybody said nothing about that so I think don't exist.

Comment: .Net's `TextFieldParser` is not a wrapper for some VB6 stuff. Also, it's not slow because it's in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (that's just silly). It's slower than a simple `String.Split` because it actually parses CSV data (and respects quotes and espacing quotes). Every proper parsing of CSV data will be slower than `String.Split`. If you're looking for a powerful parsing library, I recommend [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on false assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have compared performance with that code: https://gist.github.com/Ruszrok/7861319

I used an input file with about 1 000 000 records separated with spaces. I tried five experiments.

- `String.Split` avg time: **291 ms**
- `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` avg time: **15843 ms**

You can use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` class. Reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. Sample in gist.

Comment: However string.split will not account for the entire CSV spec - for example commas and quotes embeded in a field will not get messed up with a string.split approach - so you can use the split approach - but only it you are sure what your data will be like

Comment: Your `string.Split` test code reads only one line and splits by spaces whereas the `TextFieldParser` has to read and parse the whole file. Of course that takes some milliseconds more. But the whole comparison is nonsense. Use the right tool for a job. A `TextFieldParser` is much more powerful than a simple `String.Split` if you have real csv data (f.e. if fields are enclosed with quotes).

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
public class TextFieldParser
    {
        enum FieldType { FixedWidth, Delimited };

        public enum CompleteElements 
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Returns as many elements as fileWidths input be
            /// </summary>
            AllElements, 
            /// <summary>
            /// Only returns elements who have not null values
            /// </summary>
            OnlyValues 
        };

        int[] m_fieldWidths;
        string m_line;
        List<string> m_results;
        int m_lineWidth;
        public CompleteElements m_CompleteElements;

        public TextFieldParser(string line)
        {
            m_line = line;
            m_lineWidth = m_line.Length;
            m_results = new List<string>();
            m_CompleteElements = CompleteElements.OnlyValues;
        }

        public void SetCompleteElements(CompleteElements value) 
        {
            m_CompleteElements = value;
        }

        public void SetFieldWidths(params int[] fileWidths)
        {
            m_fieldWidths = fileWidths;
        }

        public string[] ReadFields()
        {
            int pivot = 0;
            m_results = new List<string>();

            for (int x = 0; x < m_fieldWidths.Length; x++) 
            {
                if(pivot + m_fieldWidths[x] <= m_lineWidth)
                {
                    m_results.Add(m_line.Substring(pivot, m_fieldWidths[x]));                    
                }
                else
                {
                    if (m_CompleteElements == CompleteElements.AllElements) 
                    {
                        m_results.Add(null);
                    }

                    break;
                }
                pivot += m_fieldWidths[x];
            }
            return m_results.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

A simple session:

```
string line = "1234567890123456789012345678890";
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(line);
parser.SetFieldWidths(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

string[] resultOnlyValues = parser.ReadFields();
/*
results:
resultOnlyValues[0] : "1"
resultOnlyValues[1] : "23"
resultOnlyValues[2] : "456"
resultOnlyValues[3] : "7890"
resultOnlyValues[4] : "12345"
resultOnlyValues[5] : "678901"
resultOnlyValues[6] : "2345678"
*/
parser.SetCompleteElements(TextFieldParser.CompleteElements.AllElements);
string[] resultAllElement = parser.ReadFields();
/*
results:
resultAllElement[0] : "1"
resultAllElement[1] : "23"
resultAllElement[2] : "456"
resultAllElement[3] : "7890"
resultAllElement[4] : "12345"
resultAllElement[5] : "678901"
resultAllElement[6] : "2345678"
resultAllElement[7] : null
*/
```